# Docker Swarm stack deploy specific service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have multiple services in a compose file and I need to deploy only one specific service. Does docker swarm support this?
Example of a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  bar:
    image: bar:latest
    deploy:
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 256M

  foo:
    image: foo:latest
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 256M
```

So the command to deploy to stack *mystack* both services is:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker/docker-compose.yml mystack
```

I want to deploy just *Foo* service. Expect the command to be something like:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker/docker-compose.yml foo mystack
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, this seems like a limitation with the stack deploy command as described [here on this moby issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30253). I don't think there is any road map to add this feature to Docker. Having said that, the `docker stack deploy` command should be able to do a diff and only update services that have new images or config changes in the yaml file.